# Oracle, Parse JSON with > 4000K

Tags: json, oracle, parsing

I am trying to parse some JSON like this:

```
SELECT cid, c_message
FROM JSON_TABLE('{"cid":"30152","c_message":"....very long message...."}'
FORMAT JSON,'$[*]'
       COLUMNS (cid                  NUMBER          PATH '$.cid',
                c_message            VARCHAR2(4000)  PATH '$.c_message'));
```

The issue here is that c_message is > 4000 bytes.   And, I have tried making the length VARCHAR2(32000) and it still does not work.

How can I parse the JSON when the length exceeds 4000k?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `clob` datatype instead. `varchar2(32000)` is available only when `max_string_size` database parameter is set to `EXTENDED`

Comment: If I change VARCHAR2 to CLOB, I get an error:   ORA-40484: invalid data type for JSON_TABLE column

Comment: First, it's 4000 or 4K. 4000K is 4 million - your strings aren't THAT long. Second, are you copying the string (the JSON) from somewhere and including it in your query as a hardcoded string? If so, the problem has nothing to do with JSON. Oracle does not support CLOB literals; what you are giving is a string literal, and the max allowed length is 4K bytes, or ~32K bytes if you change the database parameter (you can't just declare varchar2(32000) if the db parameter is still `STANDARD`).

Comment: `CLOB` is a valid data type to use in the COLUMNS clause of `JSON_TABLE`. You may need to share your updated query to continue troubleshooting. Also, you should not be specifying a character lenth after `CLOB` if you are.

Comment: As commented above, clob is a valid datatype, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b9c86a6ebea0da00cfca51acf2b8f37f)

Comment: Yes, 4000k was a typo.    Meant 4k.    I wound up performing a STARTUP UPGRADE to increase max_string_size.    I was not able to get the query working, replacing VARCHAR2(32000) with CLOB.    But also, I am finding out that the JSON has other characters, like backslash (\) and some double quotes ("), which are causing some not to parse.   So, need to see if those can be escaped or something.

Comment: But then, you have a different question, not related to string length.

Comment: Yeah, forget about the characters right now.    I did find a JSON with a c_message > 32k.   So, now I think getting the CLOB to work will be necessary.     EJ Egyed, do you have any example of this you can share?

Comment: What Oracle version are you on? CLOB was added as a JSON_TABLE column type in 12.2.

Comment: Your query can be slightly modified to return a clob for the c_message like below. As kfinity stated, you will need Oracle 12.2. What version are you using?

`SELECT cid, c_message
  FROM JSON_TABLE ('{"cid":"30152","c_message":"....very long message...."}' FORMAT JSON,
                   '$[*]'
                   COLUMNS (cid NUMBER PATH '$.cid', c_message CLOB PATH '$.c_message'));`